Solr data import handler (DIH) not found
Following the guide in readme https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler
the command that caused the exception
solr package add-repo data-import-handler "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/searchscale/dataimporthandler/master/repo/"
Exception stacktrace:
 Error from server at http://localhost:8983/admin/info/system?wt=javabin&version=2: Expected mime type in [application/octet-stream, application/vnd.apache.solr.javabin] but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/admin/info/system</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.checkContentType(Http2SolrClient.java:974)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.processErrorsAndResponse(Http2SolrClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.processErrorsAndResponse(Http2SolrClient.java:576)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:533)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1192)
        at org.apache.solr.cli.PackageTool.getZkHost(PackageTool.java:372)
        at org.apache.solr.cli.PackageTool.runImpl(PackageTool.java:90)
        at org.apache.solr.cli.ToolBase.runTool(ToolBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI.main(SolrCLI.java:153)

ERROR: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/admin/info/system?wt=javabin&version=2: Expected mime type in [application/octet-stream, application/vnd.apache.solr.javabin] but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/admin/info/system</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>


The strangest thing is that when I run this application in a Docker container and it command works.
Solr version 9.4.0-slim.
Thanks!
Im trying: run in docker, change version solr, starts cmd with admin root

There seems to be a /solr part missing in your request URL? /solr/admin/info/system - do you have the wrong base url configured/defined somewhere?

@MatsLindh It is unlikely that the newly downloaded, clean configuration was used, both locally and in the docker container.
Admin dashboard url is active: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/.
Thanks for assumption!
